# How can I use Perl for in-place-editing of files with Unix-EOL on Windows?

Tags: perl, line-endings, file-manipulation

I am trying to use Perl's *in-place-editing* feature to change some text in files with Unix line endings in a PowerShell session on Windows:

```
perl.exe -i'.bak' -p -e "s#PATTERN#REPLACEMENT#g" (get-childItem *.sql,*/*.sql)
```

Unfortunately, the line endings are changed from Unix to Windows.

Is there an option to tweak this one liner so that it doesn't modify the line endings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, on Windows, the [`:crlf` PerlIO layer](https://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO#:crlf) is used by default, which converts to and from CRLF line endings in the file to LF in the strings `perl` sees. Traditionally, the `:raw` PerlIO layer would be used to prevent this, but according to [the documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO#:raw):

> If you want UNIX line endings on a platform that normally does CRLF translation, but still want UTF-8 or encoding defaults, the appropriate thing to do is to add `:perlio` to the PERLIO environment variable, or open the handle explicitly with that layer, to replace the platform default of `:crlf`.

You can use the [`open` pragma](https://perldoc.perl.org/open) to change the default layers for opening files (And/or use the three argument version of `open` to customize them on a per-file basis).

In my testing (using Strawberry Perl 5.32), using `:perlio` with that pragma still did line ending conversion despite the above, so `:raw` it is. (However, `perlio` works with the `PERLIO` environment variable. It looks like when set that way it replaces the default layers, when used with the pragma it appends to the defaults instead despite what the documentation suggests.)

So,

```
PS> perl.exe -Mopen="IO,:raw" -i'.bak' -p -e "s#PATTERN#REPLACEMENT#g" (get-childItem *.sql,*/*.sql)
```

or

```
PS> $env:PERLIO="perlio"
PS> perl.exe -i'.bak' -p -e "s#PATTERN#REPLACEMENT#g" (get-childItem *.sql,*/*.sql)
```